# Перенаправление всех запросов на index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Проблема: в htaccess есть правило перенаправления для всех запросов на index.php, но запросы типа example.com/api (на сайте есть директория api) показывают файловый проводник(index of).
Правила перенаправления:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалите `RewriteCond`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` — все существующие папки не будут обрабатываться регулярным выражением

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` — все существующие файлы не будут обрабатываться регулярным выражением